# Safely access a property inside a nested javascript object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The object structure is as follows.

```
object = {
  obj1: {
    obj2: {
       name: 'MY name'
    }
  }
}
```

This structure is dynamic and sometimes there wont be an obj1.

So, In react you will be writing the code like..

```
object && obj1 && obj2 && obj2.name
```

so that only if object, obj1, and obj2 are present then obj2.name will be displayed.

> In this case there wont be any undefined error since the presence of each object is checked prior to going inside the function.

**Is there alternate way to the  above code so that it displays the name when all the objects are present.
If not, it should not throw an error.**

Comment: You could just catch the error

Comment: Have a look at [lodash.get](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.get).

Comment: … or write something that gets the “path” to the property passed in string form - then split that up, and recursively check if the “next” one is defined or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33444711/js-object-has-property-deep-check

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question ?

Comment: I used lodash.get

Answer (score 0):

Use hasOwnProperty to check if obj1 is present or not

```js
object = {
  obj1: {
    obj2: {
       name: 'MY name'
    }
  }
}
if(object.hasOwnProperty('obj1'))
console.log(object.obj1.obj2.name)
else
console.log(object.obj2.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
object = {
  obj1: {
    obj2: {
       name: 'MY name'
    }
  }
}
    
var name = (object.hasOwnProperty('obj1'))  ? object.obj1.obj2.name : object.obj2.name;
console.log(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check every property before reading a nested one:

```
const name = object && object.obj1 && object.obj1.obj2 && object.obj1.obj2.name;
```

This is laborious and verbose as you have to repeat the same thing over and over to access deeply nested properties.

I suggest to use a `safeEval` function that wraps your potentialy dangerous property access code with a try/catch and returns `undefined` if an error occurs.
This is much shorter than manually checking every property:

```
const name = safeEval(() => obj.obj1.obj2.name);
```

Here is an example:

```js
const obj = { obj1: { obj2: { name: 'Hello' } } }

function safeEval(fn) {
  try { return fn(); }
  catch { return undefined; }
}

const a = obj && obj.obj1 && obj.obj1.obj2 && obj.obj1.obj2.name;
const b = safeEval(() => obj.obj1.obj2.name);
const c = safeEval(() => obj.obj1.obj2.obj3.obj4.name);

console.log(a, b, c);
```

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend writing a recursive function that inspects the object and recurses down its children if a name is found. I see others suggested catching the error- I would advise against abusing exception handling for runtime errors like this.