# How do I fix TypeError undefined in JavaScript? All fields exist for the object

Tags: javascript, json, typeerror

In my piece of code below I receive a JSON object from a java Servlet and access the properties of that object.

JSON object:

```
{
  "redirect": "/index.html",
  "logout": "/_cloudshellProxy/_ah/logout?continue\u003d%2Findex.html",
  "status": true,
  "register": true,
  "user": {
    "email": "s@example.com",
    "username": "Yevesky",
    "college": {
      "name": "Lafayette College",
      "key": "aglzcHN0ZWFtMTlyFAsSB0NvbGxlZ2UYgICAgICAswgM"
    },
    "key": "aglzcHN0ZWFtMTlyEQsSBFVzZXIYgICAgICgxAgM"
  }
}
```

Here is how I handle the object from the servlet.

```js
fetch("/getUserInfo").then(response => response.json()).then(object =>
    {
        jsonObject = object;
        console.log(jsonObject);
        setUpUserPage(jsonObject);
        loadClasses();
    });
    
function setUpUserPage(json){
    const jsonData = json;
    var name = document.createElement("h3");
    name.innerText = String(jsonData.username);
    var uni = document.createElement("h6");
    uni.innerText = String(jsonData.college.name); // Error occurs here
    var classification = document.createElement("h6");
    console.log(jsonData.classes);
    
    if (jsonData?.isProf)
    {
        classification.innerText = "Professor";
    }
    else
    {
        classification.innerText = "Student";
    }
    var email = document.createElement("h6");
    email.innerText = String(jsonData.email);
    var spacer = document.createElement("BR");

    //change nickname link
    var changeNicknameP = document.createElement("p");
    changeNicknameP.innerText = "Change your nickname: ";
    var anchor = document.createElement("A");
    var link = document.createTextNode("here");
    anchor.setAttribute("href", "#");
    anchor.appendChild(link);
    changeNicknameP.appendChild(anchor);

    var profileContainer = document.getElementById("profile-container");
    profileContainer.appendChild(name);
    profileContainer.appendChild(uni);
    profileContainer.appendChild(classification);
    profileContainer.appendChild(email);
    profileContainer.appendChild(spacer);
    profileContainer.appendChild(changeNicknameP);
}
```

The problem is I do not understand why I am getting a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" if the object has such a property?

Is it just JavaScript or I am not following a procedure.

I do print the JSON object on console everytime to see if indeed the property exist.

Comment: Can you `console.log(typeof theObject)` to see what it's showing as? My guess is you need to JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)) to convert it from an object to a JS json object.

Comment: Try `uni.innerText = (jsonData.college && jsonData.college.name || '');`

Comment: @JoelHager Command returns 'object'.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee Returns ' ' as usual. I am new to JavaScript but why would an object of defined property have a TypeError associated with it?

Comment: I think in the response you are getting `jsonData.college` as undefined/null, so you need to make sure the object is a truthy value before you access it. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55139467/safely-access-a-property-inside-a-nested-javascript-object)

Comment: Yeah that is actually the problem. 'college' property is said to be undefined but when printed in console shows the name and key property just like in the JSON object shown above. The question is why?

Comment: I believe college is a property of user and not the whole object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you probably made a mistake. "college" is a property of user, not your jsonData. Replace your line with this :

```
uni.innerText = String(jsonData.user.college.name);
```

Don't forget to check properties of your object if response can change (for example is user or college are optionnal properties in some case)

PS: sorry I can't post a comment because I dont have enough point on SO.

Comment: Thanks man. Always good to have a second pair of eyes look at your code.

Comment: Your welcome ! Happy it helped. In my experience, I stopped making  this kind of mistake since I used Typescript :) You should give a try one day (depending on the time you have, the size or project and your team of course). https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html